# NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed: Xid: 79, GPU has fallen off the bus

Tags: ubuntu, crash, driver, nvidia, multi-gpu

On two occasions, the server went down when I finished training model using 4x1080ti. Why did the server crash?

I get sysylog and find something wrong about Nvidia-driver or GPUs.

Syslogs: (and the [nvidia-bug-report.log](https://github.com/eler/git_examples/blob/master/nvidia-bug-report.log))

**[the second one]**

> Sep 6 21:11:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [31429.221258] NVRM:
>   RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:682)
>
> Sep 6 21:11:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [31429.221337] NVRM:
>   rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
>
> Sep 6 21:13:54 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [31562.154256] NVRM:
>   RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:682)
>
> Sep 6 21:13:54 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [31562.154306] NVRM:
>   rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 1

**[the first one]**

> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990374] NVRM:
>   GPU at PCI:0000:04:00: GPU-bc54db68-a3cb-54e9-7287-b95c69e41cf1
>
> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990375] NVRM:
>   GPU Board Serial Number:
>
> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990376] NVRM:
>   Xid (PCI:0000:04:00): 79, GPU has fallen off the bus.
>
> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990377] NVRM:
>   GPU at 0000:04:00.0 has fallen off the bus.
>
> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990377] NVRM:
>   GPU is on Board .
>
> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990655] NVRM: A
>   GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
>
> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990655] NVRM:
>   nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
>
> Sep 6 02:48:40 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557998.990655] NVRM:
>   the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
>
> Sep 6 02:48:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557999.884383] NVRM:
>   GPU at 0000:04:00.0 has fallen off the bus.
>
> Sep 6 02:48:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557999.901942] NVRM: A
>   GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
>
> Sep 6 02:48:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557999.901942] NVRM:
>   nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
>
> Sep 6 02:48:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [557999.901942] NVRM:
>   the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
>
> Sep 6 02:48:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558000.356948] NVRM:
>   RmInitAdapter failed! (0x30:0xffff:682)
>
> Sep 6 02:48:41 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558000.444379] NVRM:
>   rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
>
> Sep 6 02:48:45 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558004.604173] NVRM:
>   request_irq() failed (-22)
>
> Sep 6 02:48:48 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558007.497475] NVRM:
>   RmInitAdapter failed! (0x23:0x56:468)
>
> Sep 6 02:48:48 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558007.497489] NVRM:
>   rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
>
> Sep 6 02:48:50 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558008.878985] NVRM:
>   request_irq() failed (-22)
>
> Sep 6 02:48:53 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558011.735642] NVRM:
>   RmInitAdapter failed! (0x23:0x56:468)
>
> Sep 6 02:48:53 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558011.735658] NVRM:
>   rm_init_adapter failed for device bearing minor number 0
>
> Sep 6 02:48:54 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558013.108772] NVRM:
>   request_irq() failed (-22)
>
> Sep 6 02:48:55 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558013.757168] BUG:
>   unable to handle kernel paging request at 0000000132081000
>
> Sep 6 02:48:55 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558013.757173] IP: []
>   kmem_cache_alloc+0x77/0x1f0
>
> Sep 6 02:48:55 gpu-8-server-intesight kernel: [558013.757175] PGD
>   10357d8067 PUD 0

Comment: Z.Lin  , thank you for making it clear

Comment: Related: [NVRM: Xid: 79, GPU has fallen off the bus](https://askubuntu.com/q/974375/78223).

Answer (score 6):

We have had this issue. From what I can tell you have a very similar setup with multiple GPUs and an X99 motherboard. We managed to mitigate the error by setting `pcie_aspm=off` in the boot kernel parameters. I you search for "aspm" in the nvidia bug report logs that you have provided, you will notice the following:

> [ 0.167842] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
>
> [ 0.278085] acpi PNP0A03:03: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
>
> [ 0.282583] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
>
> [ 2.795337] r8169 0000:0a:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control

We still have some issues at the moment with our GPU server, but it's likely that this will help.

I originally found this idea on this [thread](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/957456/geforce-drivers/gtx-1080-throwing-bad-tlp-pcie-bus-errors/post/4969345/#4969345)

UPDATE: We still get the occasional `RmInitAdapter` message but we don't have any stability issues anymore. For the record we're now running Nvidia's 387.34 driver and we have the following boot parameters:

```
pcie_aspm=off rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1
```

As a side note, we also have a newer quad-GPU box based on a X299 motherboard and we have similar issues.

Related:

- [What does `pcie_aspm` do?](https://serverfault.com/q/226319/130437)