# Frozen black screen during the inference

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia

I am using two GPUs, Intel GPU for display and NVIDIA GPU for deep learning inference. My application requires high inference rate, I encounter a frozen black screen occasionally. The following logs were found:

```
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.1: AER: Uncorrected (Fatal) error received: 0000:00:01.1
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.1: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.1:   device [8086:1905] error status/mask=00004000/00000000
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:01.1:    [14] CmpltTO                (First)
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: nvidia 0000:06:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:06:00.1: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:06:00: GPU-1b5482a1-8e21-c703-a530-cf77ae833803
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:06:00): 79, pid='<unknown>', name=<unknown>, GPU has fallen off the bus.
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: NVRM: GPU 0000:06:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus.
feb 08 13:20:39 control-0001 kernel: [133B blob data]
```

I read somewhere (https://askubuntu.com/questions/868321/gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus-nvidia) that it could be due to persistent mode.
Can someone suggest what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NVRM: RmInitAdapter failed: Xid: 79, GPU has fallen off the bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107222/nvrm-rminitadapter-failed-xid-79-gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus)

Comment: This can be too many possible issues, including hardware issues, and has been asked and answered before.

Comment: The error is different.

Comment: It looks the same: Xid  79 and GPU has fallen off the bus. In any case this is unanswerable without more details or debugging from your side.